# Probability of randomly matching two people

Tags: probability

A dating site allows users to select $6 $ out of $25$ adjectives to describe their likes and preferences. A match is said to be found between two users on the website if they match on at least $ 5$ adjectives. If Brad and Angelina randomly pick adjectives, what is the probability that they will form a match?

Comment: There are $25$ balls and exactly $6$ of them are red. If you pick randomly $6$ balls (without replacement) then what is the probability that at least $5$ of them are red? Can you solve this yourself? It is actually the same problem.

Comment: Identify yourself with Brad. Think of the $25$ balls as the adiectives and of the $6$ red ball as the adiectives selected by Angelina. Have a look at [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Comment: Thank you very much so N is $=25$ K $=5$ n is $=6$ in Hypergeometric distribution right?

Comment: $N=25$ (number of balls/adiectives) $K=6$ (number of red balls/adjectives selected by Angelina) $n=6$ (number of draws/selections made by you/Brad). There is a match if there are at least $5$ successes, so you must find the probability for $k=5$ and $k=6$. Then addition gives the probability of at least $5$ successes.